# How can I solve this font rendering issue on Firefox on OSX?

Tags: html, css

I've run into a strange font rendering issue on Firefox on OSX.  It seems to be adding an extra pixel above the font whereas Firefox on Windows does not.

[http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/dc9a946ffc5a0198f6b45425c1d91970.png](http://vulc4n.com/dm/)

Comment: screenshot: http://hostthenpost.org/uploads/dc9a946ffc5a0198f6b45425c1d91970.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want pixel perfect rendering, you should probably specify a pixel value for the `line-height`.

From my tests, `line-height:14px` to match the FF height and `line-height:13px` to match the Chrome height.